# ResourceDictionary as NuGet Package

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nuget-package

I'm currently trying to create sort of a XAML "Style collection" which we can use in all of our UI projects, to achieve consistency in our visuals.

I've tried creating a class library and added a `ResourceDictionary` with my style:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="ToggleSwitch" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        Some style in here
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Enabled building the NuGet Package in the build options and added it to another UI project.
I just can't quite get my head around about how to actually use the style in the UI project now.

Is this even a valid approach?
Googling this specific intend didn't get me any reasonable results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a valid approach and it is no different from creating and consuming resource dictionaries locally, except for how you reference them if they are located in a referenced assembly.

As an example for the application resources for an assembly `YourReferencedAssembly.dll` and a resource dictionary `YourStyleResourceDictionary.xaml` directly within the assembly.

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <!-- ...other resources. -->
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <!-- ...other resource dictionaries. -->
         <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourReferencedAssembly;component/YourStyleResourceDictionary.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The source path is a so-called [*pack URI*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and can  take various forms. You can refer to the [resource file pack URI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#resource-file-pack-uris). This is how the [path for resources in referenced assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#referenced-assembly-resource-file) looks in detail:

> Authority: `application:///`.
>
> Path: The name of a resource file that is compiled into a referenced assembly. The path must conform to the following format:
>
> `AssemblyShortName{;Version]{;PublicKey];component/Path`
>
> AssemblyShortName: the short name for the referenced assembly.
>
> `;Version` [optional]: the version of the referenced assembly that contains the resource file. This is used when two or more referenced assemblies with the same short name are loaded.
>
> `;PublicKey` [optional]: the public key that was used to sign the referenced assembly. This is used when two or more referenced assemblies with the same short name are loaded.
>
> `;component:` specifies that the assembly being referred to is referenced from the local assembly.
>
> `/Path`: the name of the resource file, including its path, relative to the root of the referenced assembly's project folder.

*Implicit* styles, as usual, are automatically applied in the scope where the resource dictionary is added and *explicit* styles are referenced either using `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource`. There is no difference where the resource dictionary comes from, the same assembly or a different one.

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed answer :).
Worked exactly like i wanted it to, have a good one!